# How to use an enum as one would use an interface?

Tags: java, interface, enums, polymorphism

How can I assign SomeEnum1 or SomeEnum2 to an "enum" which implements SomeInterface? I can't just specify the interface directly as it's a class and not an enum.

I'm sure there is a specify syntactic sugar to make this work but I can't figure it out.

Example:

```
public class Main {
   public interface SomeInterface {
       public String doSomething();
   }

   public enum SomeEnum1 implements SomeInterface {
      something1;

      @Override
      public String doSomething() {
         return "SomeEnum1";
      }
   }

   public enum SomeEnum2 implements SomeInterface {
      something2;

      @Override
      public String doSomething() {
         return "SomeEnum2";
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      // Works but not polymorphic
      SomeEnum1 e1 = SomeEnum1.something1;
      System.out.println(e1.name() + " " + e1.doSomething());

      // Not an enum
      // SomeInterface e2 = SomeEnum1.something1;
      // System.out.println(e2.name() + " " + e2.doSomething());

      // Bounds mismatch
      // Enum<SomeInterface> e3 = SomeEnum1.something1;
      // System.out.println(e3.name() + " " + e3.doSomething());
   }
}
```

Comment: so you would like to use `SomeInterface` as an `enum`? In that case you would need `SomeInterface` to extend `Enum`, which isn't possible.

Even if you replaced `SomeInterface` with `SomeAbstractClass`, it still wouldn't be possible because all `enum`s extend from `java.lang.Enum`, and Java doesn't support multiple inheritance.

Comment: `How can I assign SomeEnum1 or SomeEnum2 to an "enum"` you can't, enums can't be extended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass the value to a method, you can use generics to restrict the type of `SomeInterface` by 2 constraints:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    print(SomeEnum1.something1);
}

public static <T extends Enum & SomeInterface> void print(T t) {
    System.out.println(t.name() + " " + t.doSomething());
}
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I wanted. I had no idea that you could use `&` in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.
An enum type can, in Java, only have values defined for that enum type.

The closest thing to what you want you actually ansered yourself:

```
SomeInterface e2 = SomeEnum1.something1;
```

**Edit:** To be able to use the `name()` method, you will need to add it to the interface like so:

```
public interface SomeInterface {
    public String doSomething();
    public String name();
}
```

As that method is already available on any Enum, you don't have to re-implement it.

<strike>Are there specific reasons why you want that to be an enum? Using this approach here you get all the functionality defined in `SomeInterface`. I cannot imagine why you would need an enum here -> please elaborate if my answer is not close to what you need.</strike>

Comment: The reason being I want to keep access to `.name()` without having to implement it in the interface. Although even if I implement it, I can then call `.name()` when I `@Override`.

Comment: Just add `name()` to the interface.. See my edited answer -> that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the enum implement an interface, you can declare a static method and provide an implementation for each enum value.

```
public enum Animal {

    DOG {
        public void makeNoise() { System.out.println("Bark bark!"); }
    },

    CAT {
        public void makeNoise() { System.out.println("Prrrrr!"); }
    };

    public abstract void makeNoise();

}
```

That way you can use it like this:

```
Animal animal = Animal.DOG;
animal.makeNoise(); // prints "Bark bark!";

animal = Animal.CAT;
animal.makeNoise(); // prints "Prrrrr!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do:

```
SomeInterface e2 = SomeEnum1.something1;
```

The problem is that `e2` is an interface, which can be implemented by any class, also classes which do not have a `name()` method. So if you want to access that method from `SomeInterface`-type references, you will have to include it in the interface:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    String name();
}
```

However, note that `SomeInterface` is still not an enum, so your can't switch on it, cannot use `EnumSet` and `EnumMap`, etc. Usually there are better solutions.